# Objective C How to implement properly Protocol or another solution

Tags: ios, objective-c, design-patterns, delegates, protocols

I have a question.
Give me a bone, how to implement this properly

The example code below. From viewController I will call "updateViewData:" method for update data in ViewClass. NewData array should contain Array of DataModels instances

So my question. I want to secure code, if another developer will call "updateViewData:" with not array of DataModel instances .

What is the best way to solve this question, write NSException or write some protocol for that or maybe subclass of NSMutableArray that will check added data to array.

I will be appreciated if answers will contain examples.

Big thanks.

```
//View
@interface ViewClass : UIView
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *viewData;

- (void)updateViewData:(NSArray *)newData;
@end


@implementation ViewClass
- (void)updateViewData:(NSArray *)newData
{
   self.viewData = newData;

   [self.tableView reloadDate];
}
@end


//Model
@interface DataModel : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSDate   *date;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *name;

@end
```

Answer (score 1):

I would simply return boolean success code:

```
- (BOOL)updateViewData:(NSArray *)newData
{
    for (id obj in newData)
        if (![obj isKindOfClass:[DataModel class]])
            return NO;

    self.viewData = newData;

    [self.tableView reloadDate];
    return YES;
}
```

Throwing an exception seems a bit extreme, however it's really up to you.